# struts 2 autocompleter

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, struts2

```
<ajax:autocompleter name="cityName" list="list" size="1" label="Select City" 
    listValue="cityName" listKey="id" autoComplete="true"></ajax:autocompleter>
```

i am using struts 2 with ajax but its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
&lt;%@ taglib prefix="ajax" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>

**&lt;ajax:head  />**


&lt;ajax:autocompleter name="cityName" list="list" size="1" label="Select City" 
    listValue="cityName" listKey="id" autoComplete="true"></ajax:autocompleter>
```

Make sure <ajax:head/> is in the <head></head> of the jsp. It generates the required code for autogeneration.

Answer (score 0):

you should use struts url tag to call an action which gives u json object as list

```
<s:url id="List" action="/actionName" method="methodName" />
<sx:autocompleter id="itemC" href="%{List}" forceValidOption="true" preload="true"
size="24" name="item" autoComplete="false" showDownArrow="false"    
valueNotifyTopics="/value"></sx:autocompleter>
```

Comment: import struts dojo tag library <%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%> and add <sx:head/> between <head></head> in jsp page. and also ensure that you have included all required struts jar files in your project.